# SQLite3 querying error

Tags: php, sqlite

I need some help with my code. I get this error:

> PHP Warning:  SQLite3::query(): Unable to prepare statement: 1, near `=`: syntax error in `/var/www/html/image.php` on line 16
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchArray() on boolean in /var/www/html/image.php:17`
>
> Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 {main}
>
> thrown in /var/www/html/image.php on line 17

This is my code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
Header("Content-type: image/png");
$im = imagecreate(304, 214);
$blanco = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
imagerectangle($im, 0, 0, 304, 214, $blanco);
$rojo = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 0, 0);
$verde = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 255, 0);
$azul = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 255);
$amarillo = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 0);
$violeta = imagecolorallocate($im, 46, 49, 146);
$naranja = imagecolorallocate($im, 242, 101, 34);
$negro = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

if ($db = new SQLite3 ('/var/www/html/db/SeriesDb.sqlite')) {
    $q = $db-> query("SELECT * FROM tbl_Series where id "= .$_REQUEST["id"]);
    while ($row = $q-> fetchArray()) {
        $id = $row[0];
        $dayweek = date("N", strtotime($row[1]));
        $serie = explode(" ",$row[2]);
    }
} else {
    die("error");
}

switch ($dayweek) {
    case 7: $color = $rojo;
        break;
    case 6: $color = $naranja;
        break;
    case 5: $color = $amarillo;
        break;
    case 4: $color = $verde;
        break;
    case 3: $color = $azul;
        break;
    case 2: $color = $violeta;
        break;
    case 1: $color = $negro;
}
$j = 0;
$y = 0;
$x = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < 70; $i++) {
    $j++;
    if ($j > 10)
        $j = 1;
    $x = 30 * $j - 28;
    $y = $i % 10 == 0 ? 2 + ($i / 10) * 30 : $y;
    imagerectangle($im, $x, $y, $x + 30, $y + 30, $negro);
    if (in_array($i + 1, $serie))
        imagefilledrectangle($im, $x + 1, $y + 1, $x + 30 - 1, $y + 30 - 1, $color);
}
Imagepng($im);
Imagedestroy($im);
$db->close();
```

What could the problem be?

Comment: thank you very much; cartant and sandesh jain. The problem is solved

Comment: You should accept an answer, so that your question is no longer listed as unanswered: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

The `=` sign appears to be outside the string literal to which you are concatenating `$_REQUEST["id"]`. It should be something like this:

```
$q = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_Series where id = " . $_REQUEST["id"]);
```

However, it would be better to avoid the concatenation and use a prepared statement:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_Series where id = :id");
$stmt->bindValue(":id", $_REQUEST["id"], SQLITE3_TEXT);
$q = $stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Its looks like your query is not generating properly. It is recommended to use prepare statement to add run time params into query. you can go with [this](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) tutorial.